# modf function intpart is zero?

Tags: c

What am I doing wrong I always get `intpart` equal to `0` when I enter any number ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
double x=0.,fraction=0.;
int intpart=0;
printf("read value of x :");
scanf("%lf",&x);
fraction=modf(x,&intpart);
printf("x=%f    intpart=%d   fraction=%f \n",x,intpart,fraction);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`modf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/modf.3.html) takes `double*` as its second argument. But you are passing an `int*`. So, it's [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The solution is to use a `double*`:

Change

```
int intpart=0;
```

to

```
double iptr = 0;
```

Compile with all **warnings** enabled. Clang produces the warning:

> warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int *' to parameter of
> type 'double *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

and gcc produces:

> warning: passing argument 2 of ‘modf’ from incompatible pointer type
> [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

See C11 draft, 7.12.6.12, [The modf functions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.6.12).

Comment: can you give that part in the standard stating that please ? what about casting double to int why it didn't work ?

Comment: @rondino Show us where you think you cast any `double` to `int`. If you mean 'why doesn't the compiler infer what I really want and cast for me', then thankfully, because it isn't so presumptuous.

Comment: If you mean casting an `int*` to `double*` then no, it'll create aliasing problems. Why not simply use the right type and declare `intptr` as `double`: `double iptr;`?

Comment: I do that only for educational purposes ! :) I will be really grateful if yougive me that part in the standard about your last comment !

Comment: @rondino The fact that pointers aren't implicitly converted - and with the exception of _to_ `char *` can't be explicitly converted and dereferenced - follows from the facts that (A) different pointers may have different representations, and (B) trying to access an object of one type via a pointer of another violates strict aliasing rules; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/2757035 More directly: `double *` and `int *` are different, incompatible types. The compiler will not automatically realise what you _really_ want and fix your code and/or cast between pointer types and cause aliasing.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks a lot for the explanation ! same for P.P  :)

Comment: @rondino You're welcome! It's great that you want to check the Standard! Btw, there's a thread on here somewhere that links to the final drafts of various C (and C++) versions in PDF form. I like to save these and text-search through them when looking for information, which sometimes works surprisingly well considering how big they are. ;-)